# How to use numpy.amax() on list of ndarrays of different shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of ndarrays of different shape, for example the shapes `(3072, 128), (128,), (128, 64)`.
It is no coincidence, that the last dimension of a former array matches the first dimension of the latter array – if that helps in any way.
I want to use numpy to calculate the overall maximum value of all arrays (so just one scalar). However, `numpy.amax(my_list)` returns

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know that I can avoid the problem by using an explicit `for` loop like

```
for arr in my_list:
    max_so_far = numpy.amax(arr)
    ...
```

but I would like to take advantage of numpy's broadcasting/vectorizing feature, if possible. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You cannot use broadcasting on a list, well, at least, it won't give you any speed gains. Just use the for-loop.

Comment: Concatenate all arrays into one (may need to flatten the 2d ones), and take the max.

Comment: @hpaulj I doubt you'd save any speed over a loop, the concatenation overhead would kill any speed gains I suspect

Comment: @hpaulj indeed, my quick tests with `max(map(np.max, data))` and `np.concatenate([x.flatten() for x in data]).max()` show the latter as almost 4 times slower.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I'm not surprised.  Whole array solutions often aren't faster, especially if the starting point is a list.  A modest number of loops isn't the worst thing in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

`maximum = max(arr.max() for arr in my_list)`

The most labor would be done inside each arr.max() call, which is well optimized inside numpy, and the time of the gluing Python max, which is calculated over the individual array maximas, would be negligible (provided the number of elements in the arrays is significantly larger than the total number of arrays).

Any attempts to squeeze+concatenate the arrays (to end up with some single numpy max call) would just kill the performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(3072, 128), (128, ), (128, 64)]
a = np.array(l, dtype=object)
print np.amax(np.amax(a))
# 3072
```

Comment: This will not work, this only works because the objects inside are `tuple` objects, but would fail the same as above with `np.ndarray` objects